# shorther the code if a text equal with something

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to create a game with Questions (Want to be a millionaire). Unfortunately, however, I've been stuck a bit, because what I want to do requires rewriting the code too often. Can I make this a little easier?

The first code is with Questions.

If LbNumber.Text increase +1, all code my increase +1

```
   Private Sub BttStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BttStart.Click
        Dim Rand As New Random() 'Pentru extragerea unui ` Număr ` aleatoriu)
        Dim Number = Rand.Next(1, CountQListBox.Text) 'Exemplu, Un Număr intre (1,26)
        LBNumber.Text = Number 'In Label-ul nostru denumit, LBNumber, va apărea Numarul extras.
        If LBNumber.Text = ("1") Then 'Dacă Numărul extras va fi 1
            QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(1) 'In TextBox-ul denumit, QuestionBox va apărea primul Item din ListBox 1.
            QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(1) 'Vom selecta astfel primul Item, din ListBox 1.
        ElseIf LBNumber.Text = ("2") Then
            QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(2)
            QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(2)
        ElseIf LBNumber.Text = ("3") Then
            QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(3)
            QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(3)
        ElseIf LBNumber.Text = ("4") Then
            QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(4)
            QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(4)
        ElseIf LBNumber.Text = ("5") Then
            QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(5)
            QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(5)
        End If
    End Sub
```

The 2nd with the answers.

If QListBox.Items increase +1, AnswerLoadFile.Lines increase +1. but the others not changed value.

```
 Private Sub QuestionBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles QuestionBox.TextChanged
        If QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(1) Then
            Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(1)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
            Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(1)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
            Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(1)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
            Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(1)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
            AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
            AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
            AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
            AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
        ElseIf QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(2) Then
            Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(2)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
            Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(2)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
            Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(2)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
            Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(2)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
            AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
            AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
            AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
            AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
        ElseIf QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(3) Then
            Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(3)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
            Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(3)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
            Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(3)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
            Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(3)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
            AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
            AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
            AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
            AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
        ElseIf QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(4) Then
            Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(4)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
            Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(4)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
            Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(4)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
            Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(4)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
            AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
            AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
            AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
            AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
        ElseIf QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(5) Then
            Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(5)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
            Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(5)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
            Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(5)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
            Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(5)
            Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
            AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
            AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
            AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
            AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
        End If
```

Comment: Change `Dim Rand` to `Static Rand`, or move it from local to class/form level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Private Sub BttStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BttStart.Click
    Dim Rand As New Random()
    Dim Number = Rand.Next(1, CountQListBox.Text)
    LBNumber.Text = Number
    QListBoxLoad.SelectedItem = QListBoxLoad.Items(Number)
    QuestionBox.Text = QListBoxLoad.Items(Number) 
End Sub
```

and then this:

```
Private Sub QuestionBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles QuestionBox.TextChanged
    Dim Number = QListBoxLoad.SelectedIndex
    Dim a As String : a = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(Number)
    Debug.Print(indexThroughString(a, 2))
    Dim b As String : b = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(Number)
    Debug.Print(indexThroughString(b, 3))
    Dim c As String : c = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(Number)
    Debug.Print(indexThroughString(c, 4))
    Dim d As String : d = AnswerLoadFile.Lines(Number)
    Debug.Print(indexThroughString(d, 5))
    AnswerA.Text = (indexThroughString(a, 2))
    AnswerB.Text = (indexThroughString(b, 3))
    AnswerC.Text = (indexThroughString(c, 4))
    AnswerD.Text = (indexThroughString(d, 5))
End Sub
```